# How to remove visible layer lines in illustrator or photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have a file in illustrator that partially shows layer lines of triangles intersecting small squares inside a tag image here:

[image]

That I am trying to get rid of.  Anyone know of a good way of not having these visible?  They show up a lot clearer in photoshop too?

Many thanks!

Comment: This question doesn't belong on SO. If you read the two tags that you placed on this question they both state that.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be giving them thin strokes(let's say 0.02, same color) that cover the invisible lines. You may need to move the layers a bit to keep the image the same.